# How to deploy Angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, web-deployment, angular-universal

I looking into Angular universal and trying to get my head around deployment.
Github https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

It has Angular 2 Universal +  TypeScript 2 + Webpack 2

When I run the command

```
npm run build
```

I get the following structure

```
**Client**
0.bundle
0.bundle.js.map
main.bundle
main.bundle.js.map

**Server**
0.index
0.index.js.map
index
index.js.map
```

How do I deploy this to a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install dependencies**

Run `npm install` in your terminal at the root of universal-starter

**Run the NodeJS backend**

Run `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` after npm install has finished, this will host a local nodejs server here: http://localhost:4000 (you can put that in your browser)

Before either of these steps ensure you have NodeJS and NPM installed (NPM comes with the newer builds of NodeJS)